# Does Kafka S3 Sink Connector allocate temporary files or offheap memory before commiting files to S3?

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm looking into [Kafka connect S3 sink](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/tree/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3) source code, to figure out whether it creates temporary files before uploading to S3.

What I have found is that records are appended to an in-memory [queue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/8702881c7c781ad26cb7b278ac556f75b2bd8f01/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/TopicPartitionWriter.java#L73) `Queue<SinkRecord>`. However, I also found in record writer, there is also `DataFileWriter` to write [Avro](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/8702881c7c781ad26cb7b278ac556f75b2bd8f01/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/format/avro/AvroRecordWriterProvider.java#L61) files which makes it confusing.

Can any anyone confirm whether S3 sink connector (with Avro format) creates temporary files or allocate off heap memory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does allocate a buffer, but in heap, and not files.

[This issue](https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/issues/177#issuecomment-402249805) describes how it is done with TimebasedPartitioner.